# Исключение SynchronizationLockException в AKKA.NET маилбоксах

Tags: .net, akka-http

Здравствуйте уважаемые разработчики!
Я использую AKKA.NET в моем проекте. Есть необходимость использовать маилбоксы для установки приоритетов сообщениям. 
Согласно статье https://getakka.net/articles/actors/mailboxes.html я создал mailbox:

```
    public class MyActorMailBox: UnboundedPriorityMailbox
    {
        public MyActorMailBox(Settings settings, Config config) : base(settings, config)
        {}

        protected override int PriorityGenerator(object message)
        {
            if (message is MyActorMailBox.ErroredMessage)
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Создание экземпляра актора с маилбоксом:

```
       ActorSystem.ActorOf(
            Props.Create(() => new MyActor()).WithMailbox("myactor-mailbox"), "MyActor");
```

После этого я добавил настройку в App.config

```
  <!-- language: lang-xml -->
  <akka>
    <hocon>
      <![CDATA[
      akka
      {...}
      myactor-mailbox
      {     
         mailbox-type="MyActorMailBox, MyAssembly"
      }
      ]]>
    </hocon>
  </akka>
```

Получаю System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
Я предполагаю, это связано с несинхронизированной очередью сообщений в маилбоксе по умолчанию. Представленный ниже стек вызовов не содержит информации о типе сообщения:

```
Swallowing exception during message send
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
   at Akka.Dispatch.MessageQueues.BlockingMessageQueue.Enqueue(IActorRef receiver, Envelope envelope)
   at Akka.Dispatch.MessageDispatcher.Dispatch(ActorCell cell, Envelope envelope)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.SendMessage(Envelope message)
```

Есть у кого какие-либо идеи?
Спасибо

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке, пожалуйста переведите.

Comment: Я использую AKKA.NET и мне необходимо добавить маилбоксы для установки приоритета сообщениям согласно статье:  https://getakka.net/articles/actors/mailboxes.html
Я предполагаю, что это связано с очередью сообщений маилбокса, которая несинхронизирована. Стек вызовов не содержит деталей о типе принятого сообщения, которое вызывает проблему

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "править" под вопросом и переведите текст вопросов, чтобы вопрос соответствовал правилам сайта.